2011 Honda CRZ - Check IMA System Alert
I have had Check IMA System light/warning coming up frequently on my 2011 Honda CRZ. The thing is that it goes away for few days and comes back again. There is no pattern here.
I tried to read the codes using AutoLink AL319 but it says there are no codes.
Car works fine, runs fine, and all the systems are working just fine so I have been kind of ignoring it but I have a long road trip coming so I want to make sure that the car is safe to drive.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
